# What does $y^k(t_0) = y_k$ mean and how is it pronounced?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I just started studying differential equations and came across two equations in the Initial Value Problems section and can't proceed until I understand what the above means.  Also, what is the significance of the uppercase Y on the right side of the equation?

Context:

The interval of validity for an IVP with initial condition(s)

$y(t_0) = y_0$ and $y^k t(0) = y_k$

is the largest possible interval on which the solution is valid and contains 
$t_0$.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please [edit] the question, using mathjax to format the mathematics.https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference If you give us a little more context (a few sentences surrounding the equation) we will be better able to help you.

Comment: With the expression between dollar signs, you can use the underscore character, '_',   to create a subscript. "Y_k" will produce this -- $Y_k$ 
Please edit your question and show the expression in your post.

Comment: Is it possible (if the current answer does not solve your problem) to provide an image or link to the origin of your expression?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't get the formatting right yet. I think you mean
$$
y^k( t_0) = y_k 
$$
or, better, 
$$
y^{(k)}( t_0) = y_k .
$$
That's read as

> The $k$th derivative of $y$ at time/point $t_0$ is $y_k$.

The first statement tells you the value of $y$ at $t_0$ (which can sometimes be thought of as the zeroth derivative).

The overall meaning is that in this initial value problem you are told the value of $y$ and its first $k$ derivatives at a particular point.

Comment: One should add that this non-standard notation of the derivative should always come with such a defining statement. Usual is $y^{(k)}(t_0)$. $y^k(t)$ is the $k$-th (contravariant) coefficient of some coordinate vector, or the $(k-1)$-fold composition of $y$ with itself or seldom the $k$th power of the values of $y$.

Comment: @LutzL Indeed. See my edit.

Comment: I have corrected the question title.  The body of the question had it correct.  However, I don't know whether to edit the upper-case Y to lower case or not because, although it wasn't upper case in the text, I SAW it as upper case last night and that was part of my confusion.  I guess I will go ahead and change it to lower case y.

Comment: But what does $y_k$ mean?  I don't recognize that notation.

Comment: @postoak: It is the $(k+1)$th component of the vector $(y_0,y_1,...,y_{n-1})$ of an initial condition for an order $n$ differential equation $$y^{(n)}(t)=f(t,y(t),y'(t),...,y^{(n-1)}(t)).$$

Comment: Thank you LutzL.  How is it a vector?  Vectors have directions don't they? Where was I supposed to have studied anything using this notation in Calculus1I, 2, or 3?

Comment: Sometimes a vector models a geometric object with a direction. Sometimes it's just a convenient way to keep track of a list of numbers all at once.